# HTML table show last column using media queries

Tags: html, css

Is there a way i can show only the first and last table column (last being the far right column) using CSS media queries?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Service</td>
    <td class="big">one</td>
    <td class="big">two</td>
    <td class="big">three</td>
    <td class="big">four</td>
    <td class="big">five</td>
    <td class="big">six</td>
    <td class="big">seven</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

so in the above, how can i display just the first and last columns (Service and seven)

i have tried using media queries to hide the td with a class of `big` but i need a way of keeping the last one (i cannot remove the class because its generated programatically)

Comment: add some code so we know what you're dealing with.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: ok, check my update in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide all `td` elements by default, then in a media query show the ones you want

eg.

```
<style>
td.big {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  td.big:first-child, td.big:last-child {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: @charlie, note that this [might not work on all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child), so take care.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use the nth-child selector property to hide all the columns you don't need.